# GemStone doesn't start, says "no space left"

Tags: gemstone, maglev

I'm trying to start GemStone for MagLev. Here is an error that I get in a log:

> GemStone could not create the semaphore array required for the cache.
>
> Reason:   GemStone could not retrieve the IPC identifier associated with the
>     semaphore key -704540831.  semget() error = errno=28,ENOSPC, There is no space left on the device (or, in fcntl(), there are no more record locks).

Full logs are available in [a gist](https://gist.github.com/3927739).

Does it really lack space? I have 7 GB available. Are there any other issues in my case?

Comment: What is maximum sessions set to in the keyfile?

Comment: Do you mean gemstone/seaside/etc/gemstone.key? It says "Stone Session limit: 10000 (max possible for executable)" in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've grabbed Maglev from git master and ran update script. Now it works fine.

I don't know the exact reason behind the issue but it might have been one of the following:

- I've used ruby-build and rbenv. Now I install by hand outside of rbenv.
- I had wrong kernel settings (such as shmmax). Recently I adjusted those for Postgres.
- That was an issue in Maglev itself and it has been fixed in newer versions.